# Torquebox multi tenant request response delays

Tags: jboss, timeout, request, delay, torquebox

I've a Torquebox system with this configurations:

```
version........... 2.2.0  
build............. 74
```

built with:

```
HornetQ......... 2.2.21.SNAPSHOT (HQ_2_2_21_final, 122)  
JBossAS......... 7.1.x.incremental.129  
Infinispan...... 5.1.8.Final  
Quartz.......... 2.1.5  
JRuby........... 1.7.1
```

Some times some requests (usually GET) hangs by 15 minutes, but the server continues receiving  requests.

After 1 minute torquebox returns Timeout, but the requests remains in server.

When the hanged request continues, all the other requests also continue processing what result in errors (because they returned timeout, but still continue)!

I can resolve a part of the problem using Rack-Timeout wich can limit processing time for 50 seconds and kill the delayed processed.

Do you know any way to configure Torquebox or JBoss to avoid this delays?

Answer (score 0):

This also can be emulated with a sleep in a request and than make any other request to server.

Both requests give timeout, but remains in server pool to be executed after sleep time.

Answer (score 0):

I configured in application.rb the parameter that looks like a solution:

config.allow_concurrency = true

Do you see any problems or contraints using it?